# string manipulation remove parts of a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch file and it has a variable set to a text file the problem is I also need to make a folder with the variable name but need the remove ".txt" from the variable

the user selects a text file so list will be something like
list.txt so the variable will also be list.txt but i need to remove the .txt from the variable

I have tried searching online but couldnt find a soluntion

```
set /p list=list name: 
mkdir %list%
```

The varible to change form list.txt to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the file extension from the file name it is a very simple `FOR` command to do so.  If you read the help file for the `FOR` command you will see that you can modify the `FOR` variable output very easily.  Open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help.  The very last sections explains how you can modify the output of a file name and file path.

If you want to remove the extension and just get the base file name you can do this.

```
set /p "list=list name:"
FOR %%G IN ("%list%") DO SET "list=%%~nG"
mkdir "%list%"
```